# Assembly function on strings

Tags: string, assembly, sequence

I made function which should return the number of the highest sequence of the same character in a string. So in case of string 'aabbbcaaaabbccc' it should be 4, in case of 'aaaaa' it should be 5. So for 'aaaaa' this function should return 5, actually it returns 2. I am staring on it long time, but I can't see a mistake.

```
    unsigned long najdlhsia(const char *vstup) {
    __asm {
        mov eax, 0
        mov ecx, 0
        mov ebx, vstup
        cmp [ebx], 0
        je k
        mov edx, [ebx]
        add ebx, 1
        inc eax
        inc ecx
        c: cmp byte ptr[ebx], 0
           je p
           cmp [ebx], edx
           jne a1
           inc ecx
           add ebx, 1
           jmp c
           a1: cmp ecx, eax
               jng a2
               mov eax, ecx
           a2: mov ecx, 1
               mov edx, [ebx]
               add ebx, 1
               jmp c
            p: cmp ecx, eax
               jng k
               mov eax, ecx
        k:
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", najdlhsia("aaaaa"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am staring on it long time, but I can't see a mistake." Then it's time for you to start using a debugger. Staring can help you spot mistakes, but a debugger delivers hard facts.

Comment: y so complicated? just have a register for current character (al), one for the previous character (ah), one for the current length (ecx), one for the longest (edx) and one for the remaining string (esi). load one character (al) at a time (and not 4 in your solution. `cmp [ebx], 0` compares dword-wise), then do something like this: loop: { al = byte [esi], esi++, ( al == 0 )?: { break }, ( ah != al )?: { ( ecx > edx )?: { edx = ecx }, ecx = 0, ah = al } } return edx; your code is quite confusing, use better labels and comments eg. for the purpose of each register.

Comment: `cmp [ebx], edx` has 32-bit operand-size.  You're operating on 4 consecutive `char`s at once.  You want `cmp [ebx], dl`

Comment: solved by Peter Cordes, thanks, can be closed